# Caldera Forms Frontend Editing by User

Tags: php

I'm working on a website and using several caldera forms.  I want my users to be able to edit any of the forms.

I found this https://calderaforms.com/doc/caldera_forms_render_entry_id/ and it works great for just ONE form.  Notice that it doesn't save the form ID in the database.

```
<?php
/**
 * On form load, check for a saved entry for current user
 */
add_filter( 'caldera_forms_render_entry_id', function ( $entry_id, $form ){
    //change form ID to match your form
    if( 'CF1234567' == $form[ 'ID' ] && get_current_user_id() ){
        $saved_entry_id = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'form_entry_id' );
        if( 0 < absint( $saved_entry_id ) ){
            $entry_id = $saved_entry_id;
        }
    }

    return $entry_id;
}, 10, 2);

/**
 * On form submit, save the entry ID as user meta
 */
add_action( 'caldera_forms_submit_complete', function( $form, $form_link_array, $process_id, $entry_id ){
    //change form ID to match your form
    if( 'CF1234567' == $form[ 'ID' ] && get_current_user_id() ){
        update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'form_entry_id', $entry_id );
    }

}, 10, 4);
```

Any suggestions on code changes that will let me do what I need?

Thanks!